# JS Переопределение метода

Tags: javascript

Как называется такой способ создания объекта? Возможно ли после его создания выполнить подмену какой либо функции-члена (`function1` например):

```
var f = function(e) {
    function t() {
        var e;
        return function(e, t) {
            if (!(e instanceof t)) throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")
        }(this, t), (e = function(e, t) {
                return !t || "object" !== er(t) && "function" != typeof t ? rr(e) : t
            }(this, nr(t).call(this))).state = e._getState(), e
    }

    var n, r, o;
    return function(e, t) {
        e.prototype = Object.create(t && t.prototype, {
            constructor: {
                value: e,
                writable: !0,
                configurable: !0
            }
        }), t && ir(e, t)
    }(t, i.a.Component), n = t, (r = [{
        key: "function1",
        value: function() {
            ...
        }
    }, {
        key: "function2",
        value: function() {
            ...
        }
    }]) && tr(n.prototype, r), o && tr(n, o), t
}();
```

P.S.: Прошу строго не судить, в JS не разбираюсь. Извиняюсь за коряво вырванный пример кода, но, думаю, суть происходящего тут должна быть понятна.

Comment: о каком способе создания объекта идет речь?

Comment: Из пар key value формируются свойства и методы объекта. Я не знаю как такой способ называется, не встречал такого. Поясните ещё пожалуйста с чего мой вопрос вы отметили как дубликат? Вы видите совпадение приведённых примеров кода?

Comment: В прошлом показан пример, что подменять можно используя прототип объекта. Приведенный код в данном случае ничем не отличается от приведенного в твоем прошлом вопросе, кроме того, что там была старая функция React, а здесь похоже приведен результат сборки нового синтаксиса с классом. Лучше приводить код *до* сборки. По этому коду и _перегружать_ будет проще.

Comment: Просто странно, что я не вижу имени типа. Как выцепить этот объект из глобальной области видимости? В прошлом примере можно было просто вызвать require.

Comment: О каком типе идет речь? В приведенном коде в принципе объект возвращает, у объекта можно взять прототип, дальше как в предыдущем вопросе. Либо свойства можно напрямую в объекте менять. В данном случае это возможно

Comment: Дело в том, что этот объект нужно ещё как то получить. В глобальной области видимости его нет. Я работаю с сайтом и не могу редактировать скрипт, вставлять свой код после создания объекта...

Comment: Ранее я могу выполнить require, получить нужный объект и в дальнейшем с ним работать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95777/discussion-between-grundy-and-d-stark).